# What would be the datastructure in following scenario? (Stack with maximum)

Tags: data-structures

Please note that there is no limitation of memory. 
I need to insert int from 1 to 1000.

I can do the each of the following operations in **constant order** of time:

1. push():adds to the top
2. pop():removes the top element
3. getMax(): returns the max element

Please suggest me appropriate datastructure.

Comment: Sounds like homework. Where is your own effort?

Comment: Give us a deffinition of what this getMax should do

Comment: @Coronatus this was asked to me in an interview and i was unable to answer it. So I am looking for an answer

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stack with find-min/find-max more efficient than O(n)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134129/stack-with-find-min-find-max-more-efficient-than-on)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there is no limitation of memory, I will use 2 vectors - one for the actual data on the stack, and the other to keep track of the max at every state of the stack.
For simplicity sake I'm assuming this stack holds only +ve ints.
I know this doesn't have any error checking. But I am just providing the data structure idea here, not the full-fledged solution.

```
class StackWithMax
{
 public:
  StackWithMax() : top(-1), currentMax(0) { }
  void push(int x);
  int pop();
  int getMax() { return m[top]; }
 private:
  vector<int> v; // to store the actual elements
  vector<int> m; // to store the max element at each state
  int top;
  int currentMax;
};

void StackWithMax::push(int x)
{
  v[++top] = x;
  m[top] = max(x, currentMax);
}

int StackWithMax::pop()
{
  int x = v[top--];
  currentMax = m[top];
  return x;
}
```

Comment: You also need to do something to the `m` during a pop, don't you? +1, anyway.

Comment: @Moron: Thanks for pointing that out. I've changed `pop()` now.

Answer (score -1):

Use normal stack structure and additional array for counters 
`int c[1..1000]` and variable `int maxVal=0`.

In code add actions after stack operations:

```
On push(x) -> c[x]++ ; maxVal = max(x,maxVal)
On pop():x -> c[x]-- ; if (c[x] == 0) { j=x; while(c[--j] == 0); maxVal = j; }
```

maxVal should have always maximum value.

Maybe I am wrong, this should have amortized computational complexity O(1).
It has been a long time since I have been analysing algorithms.

Comment: This is not correct.Each above operation should be completed in constant order of time.